# google calendar api (java) authentication error in dynamic web project

Tags: java, spring, google-calendar-api

The class I have written works fine as a normal Java application, but when I try to use the code in a dynamic web project I get the following authentication failure:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gdata/util/AuthenticationException
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:823)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
```

Where is the difference?

Comment: How exactly you doing interaction with Google.and it seems you are missing something in classpath

Comment: I followed this guide http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_java.html (Create Event) very strictly. also i checked classpath and included all necessary libs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at your jars and your classpath and make sure the required jars are in the project lib.

#### Edit

Also make sure those libraries are in the WEB-INF/lib folder. That's where they will be searched for by default when you are working on a dynamic web project and when you eventually deploy your project.

[Link & instructions for working with gdata](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/java_client_lib.html#gdata)

Comment: thank you
thats what i also expected, i checked it twice, unfortunately that doesnt seem to be the problem

Comment: Ah, i didn`t know that those library are needed in the WEB-INF folder, i just linked them in the project settings. That solved the problem, thank you very much!

Comment: No problem :) Don't forget to mark the approve the answer, it helps others with similar problems.